# Twilio - Twiml Enqueue timeout or redirect after fixed time

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Is there a way to redirect a call in a queue after a certain amount of time?
I know in a Twiml `<Dial>` you can set a timeout. 
Is there any way to do that in `<Enqueue>` or even `<Play>` as part of it's `waitURL`

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
<Response>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="/wait/" method="GET">
        Support
    </Enqueue>
</Response>
```

and my wait URL is:

```
<Response>
    <Play>http://com.twilio.sounds.music.s3.amazonaws.com/MARKOVICHAMP-Borghestral.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

I want to redirect the caller to voicemail if he/she has been in the queue for more than 60 seconds.

Answer (score 9):

Twilio evangelist here.

I don't beleive there is a way to set a Timeout attribute on the enqueue verb.  I think there are a couple of ways you can approach this:

1. In your waitUrl, use an mp3 that is shorter than 60 seconds.  When the track is done playing, Twilio will make another request to the waitUrl and pass you a QueueTime parameter which will tell you how long the caller has been in the queue.  If that time is > 60 seconds you can redirect that call.
2. Have a process running in your app that uses the REST API to poll the queue members and checks their waitTime.  If waittime > 60 seconds, you redirect the call.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What keyword do you use in the waitUrl xml to redirect the call to a specific phone number. The dial keyword is not available in the waitUrl xml. The redirect keyword sends the call to another xml document. Is the solution to first use a redirect keyword, then a dial keyword is the redirected xml?

Answer (score 0):

On The response, set the Play loop="x" and below that do a redirect.

```html
<Response>
    <Play loop="2">http://com.twilio.sounds.music.s3.amazonaws.com/MARKOVICHAMP-Borghestral.mp3</Play>
    <Redirect>https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/{ACT ID}/Flows/{FLOW ID}?FlowEvent=return</Redirect>
</Response>
```